# Table cell Vertical alignment not working because of a tabular environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, vertical

I'm having trouble with the vertical alignment of four multirow cells after I used a `tabular` environment inside the cells of another column.

Because the table width extended beyond the margin, I decided to use a `tabular` environment to put the content of a cell on two lines. It solved the width issue but created another on its right with the `multirow` cells not being properly centered vertically.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
%%%
\documentclass[12pt,footinput=true,headinput=true, openright]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[scottish, french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage[np]{numprint}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\gae[1]{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\small}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Déclaration} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Question} \\ \cline{3-6} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & être & ne pas ... & être & ne pas... \\ \hline
\textbf{je} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{mi} \\ {[}mi{]}\end{tabular} & \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{tha}\\ {[}ha{]}\end{tabular}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{chan eil}\\ {[}xan yil{]}\end{tabular}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{a' bheil}\\ {[}a vil{]}\end{tabular}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{nach eil}\\ {[}nax yil{]}\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{tu} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{thu}\\{[}hu{]} \end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{elle} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{i}\\ {[}i{]}\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{il} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{e}\\ {[}e{]} \end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{nous} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{sinn}\\ {[}hèn{]}\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{vous} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{sibh}\\ {[}siv{]}\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{ils / elles} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{iad}\\ {[}yad{]}\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How could it be solved?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you already try with `\multirow{14}` instead of `\multirow{7}`?  Each of your 7 table rows contains 2 lines, which adds up to a total 14 lines, hence `\multirow{14}` should result in the expected output.

Comment: Unrelated, but you could make your code a bit more readable by using the `makecell` package and something like `\makecell{\gae{thu}\\{[}hu{]}}` instead of `\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\gae{thu}\\{[}hu{]} \end{tabular}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you. I tried with `\multirow{14}` and changing using `makecell{...}` and it is almost perfect. The text should be aligned with the fourth cell and it's a little bit lower. I have no idea why. But it looks at least better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the table, you can make a sysematic use of `\makecell` and `multirowcell`. To ensure a better vertical alignment of the multitirow cells, you do not necessarily have to use the exact number of equivalent lines – you may even use a decimal number to adjust the alignment. Here, it happens that 13 lines produces a correct alignment.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
%%%
\documentclass[12pt,footinput=true,headinput=true, openright]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scottish, french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage[np]{numprint}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\gae[1]{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\small}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{makecell}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Déclaration} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Question} \\ \cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & être & ne pas ... & être & ne pas... \\ \hline
\textbf{je} & \makecell{\gae{mi} \\ {[}mi{]}} & \multirowcell{13}{\gae{tha}\\ {[}ha{]}} & \multirowcell{13}{\gae{chan eil}\\ {[}xan yil{]}}& \multirowcell{13}{\gae{a' bheil}\\ {[}a vil{]}} & \multirowcell{13}{\gae{nach eil}\\ {[}nax yil{]}} \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{tu} & \makecell{\gae{thu}\\{[}hu{]}} & & & & \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{elle} & \makecell{\gae{i}\\ {[}i{]}} & & & & \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{il} & \makecell{\gae{e}\\ {[}e{]}} & & & & \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{nous} & \makecell{\gae{sinn}\\ {[}hèn{]}} & & & & \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{vous} & \makecell{\gae{sibh}\\ {[}siv{]}} & & & & \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{ils / elles} & \makecell{\gae{iad}\\ {[}yad{]}} & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Working perfectly well. Thank you!